# How can I make my dictionary refer to List<T> values?

Tags: c#, dictionary, windows-phone-8

I have a dictionary like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, List<SmartTextItemModel>> service_ListOfItems = new Dictionary<string, List<SmartTextItemModel>>();

service_ListOfItems["bingsearch"] = MyProgramKernel.Instance.SmartTextViewModel.SmartTextStateModel.BingItemResults;
service_ListOfItems["wikipedia"] = MyProgramKernel.Instance.SmartTextViewModel.SmartTextStateModel.WikipediaItemResults;
service_ListOfItems["youtube"] = MyProgramKernel.Instance.SmartTextViewModel.SmartTextStateModel.YoutubeItemResults;
```

(SmartTextItemModel is just a simple class for containing titles, descriptions, and URLs, which are all strings. For context, see my earlier question.)

The %service%ItemResults objects, of course, are of type List<SmartTextItemModel>, and the Lists are initialized to null in the SmartTextStateModel file.

I have code in other files which modifies each `MyProgramKernel.Instance.SmartTextViewModel.SmartTextStateModel.%service%ItemResults` List like so:

```
MyProgramKernel.Instance.SmartTextViewModel.SmartTextStateModel.%service%ItemResults = some new List of type SmartTextItemModel
```

When I try to check if the Lists are null in the same file that initializes the dictionary,

```
if (service_ListOfItems[ searchService ] == null) { ... } // searchService is "bingsearch", "wikipedia", or "youtube"
```

I don't get the results I expect. The statements in the if statement always run. The List values in the dictionary are still null even though they were assigned to in a different file.

My desired behavior is that my dictionary references the Lists at `MyProgramKernel.Instance.SmartTextViewModel.SmartTextStateModel`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are looking for is not possible. Once you place a reference to the List in the dictionary, that reference refers to a specific List, and will be unaffected by future changes to the static property you used to initialize the item.

To check whether a the properties are null, you need a method that will get the list each  time you reference the dictionary. You could change the dictionary to `Dictionary<string, Func<List<SmartTextItemModel>` and assign delegates for each item using lambda expressions like so:

```
service_ListOfItems["bingsearch"] = () => MyProgramKernel.Instance.SmartTextViewModel.SmartTextStateModel.BingItemResultsl;
```

Then use `if (service_ListOfItems[searchService]() == null)` to get and call the func. (note the extra parenthesis after the indexer since you have to call the func.)

Now, this isn't exactly elegant, and you should probably consider whether there is an entirely different way to go about solving your problem. However, it should work.

Comment: Ok. I don't need to use a dictionary, but is there something else that can map these strings to the Lists at MyProgramKernel.Instance.SmartTextViewModel.SmartTextStateModel ?

Comment: Thanks! The Lambda expression worked. I'll use it in the meantime.